# Using Hammer.js in e2e testing using protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

We are trying to get protractor integrating with hammer.js to test tap/touch events within our application. Previously we extended the angular scenario dsl to incorporate it with karma e2e testing.  Looking for a way to call hammer touch events using protractor.